# Jquery switch with var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following problem as you can see below, the problem is that i can't log or send a variable c between cases. I think it will be easy for you, cuz you are clever, I've checked a api docs of jQuery but i cant find it.

```
    $('.navbar-nav>li').click(function() {
    var c = $(this).attr("class"); //This works, I getting a class name
    switch (true) {
        case $(this).hasClass('1'):
            console.log(c); // Udentified That is a problem
            call("x",c);
        break;
        case $(this).hasClass('2'):
            call("x",c);
        break;
        case $(this).hasClass('3'):
            call("x",c);
        break;
        case $(this).hasClass('4'):
            call("x",c);
        break;
        case $(this).hasClass('5'):
            call("x",c);
        break;
    }
});
function call(o,c){ // Not important part 
    $.ajax({
        url: "/" + o,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.content').empty().html(data);
            var t = document.location.hash = o;
            $('.nav.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
            }

            });
        }
    });
}
```

And JSFiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/9xafe/9/ Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Ajax call in my another function defined deep in my code. :D

Comment: that doesn't help too much... what is it doing? include code pls!

Comment: The value of `c` works everywhere in this function (see http://jsfiddle.net/9xafe/11/) so whatever your problem is, it's in `call()` or somewhere else.

Comment: what seems to be the real problem that you are facing? its working fine for me. Except for the call() method. please check that.

Comment: Yes as @Juhana has said, `c` is working everywhere, have you tested your ajax call to see if it works with some hardcoded values? Perhaps `c` is not in the format it's expecting? ie. String or an Integer?

Comment: The "not important part" is the problem. You're not using the `c` parameter anywhere in that function.

Comment: That code works on fiddle but not on my website

Comment: @robobobobo Whole function is fine but why i cant see that c in my console on website as i said fiddle works and my website with same code not.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution:

```
    $('.navbar-nav>li').click(function() {
    var c = $(this).attr("class"); //This works i getting a class name
    switch (true) {
        case $(this).hasClass('1'):
            console.log(c); // This dont works on my website
            call("domov", c);
        break;
        case $(this).hasClass('2'):
            call("x",c);
        break;
        case $(this).hasClass('3'):
            call("x",c);
        break;
        case $(this).hasClass('4'):
            call("x",c);
        break;
        case $(this).hasClass('5'):
            call("x",c);
        break;
    }
});
function call(o, c){
    console.log(c); // This is working
    $.ajax({
        url: "/" + o,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.content').empty().html(data);
            var t = document.location.hash = o;
            $('.nav.navbar-nav li.' + c).removeClass('active', function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
            }

            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but I must say, this code is very hard to read. For the sake of anyone else who will ever maintain your code (or even for yourself a year from now), consider more descriptive names for your variables and functions.

Comment: Thank for advice Have a nice rest of day!